# Custom tracking events Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Does anyone know what to write in ITEM_ID and ITEM_NAME?

```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME,name);
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "button");
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

I want to track a button click in my android app.

Answer (score 0):

it is just key. (you can see this key and value in FCM console). So you can set this Anything.

in my case, when user put cart (my app is shopping mall app) I set this as menuId.

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CURRENCY, "won");
            bundle.putInt(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, categoryId);
            bundle.putInt(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, menuId);
            bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_LOCATION_ID, storeName);
            bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, menuName);
            bundle.putInt(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE, menu_originalPrice);
            bundle.putInt(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.QUANTITY, 1);
            bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, orderComment);
            mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.ADD_TO_CART, bundle);
```

Comment: Where do i have to look in FCM console?

Comment: Check in Event Tab in FCM console

Comment: Unable to find it in FCM Console and if I put any other thing in here it shows me an error